# why does a dc motor act like this?

Tags: dc-motor

I have a 12v motor, scavenged from an inkjet printer (there isn't a model # on the motor). I have a pulley set up on the motor, that moves a load of about 375 grams. When I connect the motor to 12v, the pulley "jumps"(like a stepper motor) about a mm or so, but then stops, and wont move any more until it is disconnected and then reconnected to 12v. Why is this happening? I wasn't expecting this to happen, but actually I am building a small scale cnc, so this is actually pretty useful. The only thing is, I need a way to make this more precise, so that I can tell how much the motor moves each "jump". I would also like to know, if it is possible, how to make the motor run continuously, without stuttering.

Comment: Sounds like it is not a DC motor.  How far does it "jump?"  If only a degree or two then it may be a [stepper motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepper_motor).  If it jumps by a significant part of one revolution then it may be a [BLDC motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushless_DC_electric_motor).  Either way, it's going to need some electronics to make it spin.

Comment: @jameslarge i am positive that it isn't a stepper, as it only has 2 pins. when i disconnect the pully and the load, it still jumps, but instead of only ~1 degree, it spins 1 rotation each jump, pretty consistently. the motor also has an optical encoder wheel attached to the bottom--maybe this is a clue as to whether or not it is a bldc?

Comment: It could also be some sort of servo motor

Comment: Post a picture.

Comment: @trevor [here](https://imgur.com/a/fzM8M) are some pictures, but the motor is mounted in a housing that would be a big pain to remove. I found a picture online, which is not the exactly the same motor, but it very similar [here](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-fyMfC_eVVbg/UYr1x0KK7VI/AAAAAAAADQs/84NHtRWyceE/s1600/DSCN1598.JPG). not that the 4 of the 6 pins go to the optical encoder, only 2 connect to the motor.

Comment: @jameslarge i could only tag 1 person in a comment, so please see the above comment

Comment: what prompted you to install the motor in a machine without testing it first? ..... ..... connect low voltage DC supply to the motor. just enough for you to feel resistance when you turn the shaft by hand. ... make note of all the "resistance spots" ... reverse the voltage and check again ... what did you observe?

Comment: okay. this is really strange. i swear that when i had the load disconnected before, it rotated only one rotation each time, but now, the motor continuously spins, but it starts out pulling 4.8v and slowly rises. Very strange

Comment: that may be the reason why the printer was scrapped

Comment: "...from an inkjet printer (there isn't a model # on the motor)" - what make/model was the printer?

Comment: Considering it was probably driving paper and your load is 375 gms. you need to severely/limit/regulate current or crank up the gear ratio with more pulleys and use the optical feedback to control velocity and position and current is torque and proportional to acceleration.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 if i limit the current, it will have more torque?

Comment: torque is proportional to current but if it exceeds limit it cogs and if it  fails to commutate then it wont budge. I think it  is a quadrature ac motor that uses DC.. i.e. BLDC. Try more pulleys to reduce speed.

Answer (score 2):

This is "some undefined" servo motion control motor in a printer and not a good candidate for serious work unless you wish to waste time learning that it is neat but not a good choice.  ( Photo looks like a BLDC with optical encoder wheel for feedback and likely uses current feedback for torque limit and other embedded control methods to slowly accelerate and control velocity and position of paper.)

For a simple CNC you are far better off to research for what you need in software/ hardware and can buy off someone like Banggood or CNC site.  It depends what image file or G code and tool you need.

[image]
Here is such a low cost  kit without guide rails show which included USB to motor driver, 3 motors, gears, 2mm toothed belts, etc, 2D software and in this case laser for etching wood. We ended up using Arduino's with CNC shields and Open source GRBL Panel software for Windows.

Plan on spending as much as you might think for a decent printer.
[image]